# if statment on installed script in sbin failing

Tags: shell

I have a simple block of code that seems to fail and I'm not 100% sure why,

```
if ! -h /usr/sbin/gitploy; then
    curl  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeremyBass/gitploy/master/gitploy | sudo sh -s -- install
    [ -h /usr/sbin/gitploy ] || echoerr "gitploy failed install"
else
    gitploy gitploy_update
fi
```

fails but if I do

```
[ -h /usr/sbin/gitploy ] || echoerr "gitploy failed install"
```

by itself it works fine.  I'm sure there is a simple reason why.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do `nested if` , So you need re-create your block such as:

```
if [ ! -h /usr/sbin/gitploy ]; then
    curl  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeremyBass/gitploy/master/gitploy | sudo sh -s -- install
    [ -h /usr/sbin/gitploy ] || echoerr "gitploy failed install"
else
    gitploy gitploy_update
fi
```

Comment: ah yes, thank you for that duh moment.. cheers